# Get changed text on a input field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I know how to detect when a user has changed the text on a input field (including typing, pasting, and other means)...

But for my purpose, I need to know exactly what was changed in the text field.

For example, initially, the text field contains this:

```
This is a text
```

Then the user changes it to this:

```
This is my text
```

The script should return this to me: text position from 8 to 9 was changed to `my`.

So is there an easier way to do this without having to use a difference checker algorithm? Because it seems that if I put an event for keyup, I can detect what position was changed or deleted, but this won't detect the whole text pasted from `Ctr+V`. Anyways, I need a fast way to send the differences in a text to synchronize it with the database on the server using AJAX, kinda like Google Docs, but I feel like resending the whole text field every so on and then is very inefficient, mainly because the user may be editing a very large text field.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and jQuery code?

Comment: I currently don't have any code... I'm just trying to figure out what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var inival=$("#myinput").val();
$("#check").click(function(){ 
$("#log").empty();
var newval=$.trim($("#myinput").val());
var splitval=newval.split(' ');
    for(var i=0; i<splitval.length; i++){
    if(inival.indexOf(splitval[i])<0){
    var charindex=newval.indexOf(splitval[i]);   
    $("#log").append('text position from '+charindex+' to '+(charindex+1)+'      
was changed to '+splitval[i]+'<br>');
    }
    }
});
});
</script>


<input type="text" value="This is a text" id="myinput"><input type="button"    
value="Check" id="check"><br>
<div id="log"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1e9yvhw7/1/)

Comment: Simply using `indexOf` will not solve the problem because there might be repetitions in the text...